# fetch_assoc doesn't show first row of results

Tags: php, mysql, html

Not sure what I did wrong. I'm aware that having two `fetch_assoc` removes the first result but I don't have such a thing.

```
$sql = "$getdb
WHERE $tablenames.$pricename LIKE 'm9%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo $tableformat;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = str_replace('m9', 'M9 Bayonet', $row['Name']); 
    include 'filename.php';
    echo $dbtable;
}
```

My connect file:

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$dbname = "";
$password = "";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

require_once ('seo.php');
$dollar = '2.';
$euro = '1.9';
$tableformat = "<div class=\"CSSTableGenerator style=\"width:600px;height:150px;\"><table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th><a class=\"tooltips\">Community<span>New !</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Cash Price</th><th>Trend&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Picture&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th></tr></div>";
$getdb = "SELECT utf.id, utf.PriceMin, utf.PriceMax, utf.Name, utf.Trend , community1s.price as com_price, utf.Name, utf.Trend 
FROM utf 
INNER JOIN (select id, avg(price) price from community1 group by id) as community1s 
ON utf.id=community1s.id";
$tablenames = 'utf';
$pricename = 'Name';
$idrange = range(300,380);
```

What happens is, it fetches the first two column's fine and the rest of the row is not there and pushes the other results down one row, which messes up the data.

Here's an image to demonstrate:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7piDh.jpg

The seo.php file is just a SEO function.

Any ideas on what may be causing this issue?

EDIT:

My Output:

```
echo $tableformat;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$name = str_replace('m9', 'M9 Bayonet', $row['Name']); 
include 'filename.php';
echo $dbtable;
```

EDIT: Solved it by moving my variables around. Marked as solved.

Comment: What is `$tableformat` and `$dbtable`.and what you include from `filename.php`

Comment: @Abdulla Just my variables. There's no DB stuff in that file.

Comment: how are you fetching the results and outputting them, this is an outputting question, wheres the output.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Just added all of the output and variables.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Some Variables that did the output were in a bad place. Rearranged them and now they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is broken, and strange things happen in broken tables. `$tableformat` contains HTML that opens a `<div>` and a `<table>`, but then closes the `<div>` with the table still open.

Fix the broken HTML and you'll probably find that all is well